# Escape characters inside $_POST

Tags: php, escaping

I'm trying to solve this issue for an hour and i have no more solutions.
I need to form a sql statement using some variables and i think i need to escape the quotes inside $_POST because i get an error (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"')

Help!!
Thanks

```
$counter=$_POST["counter"];

$x=1;
$p="('','$code','$procedure0','$check0')";

while($x<$counter)
{
$p.=",('','$code','$_POST["check".$x]','$_POST["procedure".$x]')";
$x++;
};

...

$sql="INSERT INTO `proceduri` VALUES $p;";
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'` would be a PHP error, not a mysql error. You should use parameterized queries though for your query.

Comment: You close your string `",('','$code','$_POST["` <-- here. Use single quotes for string encapsulation then use the `.` for concatenating variables.

Comment: Do you want to get SQL injected? Because this is how you get SQL injected. Use prepared statements! [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) / [mySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice that your $_POST array is inside the query. Correct syntax:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $counter; $x++) {
    if ($x)
        $p .= ',';

    $p.="('','$code','" . htmlspecialchars($_POST["check".$x], ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . htmlspecialchars($_POST["procedure".$x], ENT_QUOTES) . "')";
}
```

I have added [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) func to sanitize variables before sending them to SQL server - this will prevent some possible SQL injection. Please read this to do it best way:

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = $_POST["counter"];

$x = 1;
$p = "('','$code','$procedure0','$check0')";

while($x<$counter) {
    $p.= ",('','$code','{$_POST["check".$x]}','{$_POST["procedure".$x]}')";
    $x++;
};

...

$sql="INSERT INTO `proceduri` VALUES $p;";
```

While this might work, please consider using a parameterized approach.

Comment: doesn't seem to work